# How to read and parse (local) XML-file in Prototype JS?

Tags: javascript, xml, json, prototypejs

I have to create a module in a specific project, which already uses PrototypeJS.

What I have:
- An XML File with information

What I want:
- A simple div, which displays the (with XPath filterd) Content of the XML-File.

I am complete new to PrototypeJS and dont know where to begin, so I appreciate your help.

Blessing
chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "local" you mean "client-side", you will have to :

- include a file input for the user to upload the xml file to your server
- [fetch the xml file by ajax](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/ajax/request/) (easiest way) to have it as an [xml document](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/ajax/response/prototype/responsexml/) in your javascript
- parse the xml file with [the dedicated API](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dom.asp)
- build an HTML representation of the content using text, images, etc. and include it in your div.

edit: to clarify the fetch part, here is how you can do it using Prototype:

```
new Ajax.Request('myfile.xml', {
  onSuccess: function(transport) {
    myParseXml(transport.responseXML);
  },
  onFailure: function(transport) {
    alert('Failure! Status code '+transport.status+' ('+transport.statusText+')');
  }
);

function myParseXml(xmlDoc) {
  var root = xmlDoc.documentElement;
  ...
}
```

Comment: But this is the point: How do I fetch the xml file?
Local means the file is located in the same directory as my Script.

Comment: Ok, then it's not _local_, it's _distant_, ie on server-side as opposed to client-side. I'll edit my answer to help you understand how you can fetch the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<xml src="MyData.xml" id="mydata" >
var mydata = document.getElementById('mydata');
```

Comment: Add some description about your solution. Refer: [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)